# Delete & Reload a "Add in" from Excel (Online & desktop app)

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I want to know if there is way to delete/remove "Add-in" i have added in my online excel file (o365),currently I see remove (x) button in excel desktop app and it works like a charm it also has a reload option to just reload any particular "Add-in".

None of the two options (delete & reload)I could find in Online excel version, although for reload a simple f5 is enough,I am having a difficult time figuring out how to disable a addin i added for experimental use,I end up deleting the whole excel file which is very ridiculous,hope I am missing a simple trick and anybody can help me through.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to add to Sudhi's answer:  to fully remove an add-in from the document (rather than just make a task-pane invisible, but still keep the underlying application there, and still have it persist its settings and bindings and etc.), you would need to use the Document Inspector:  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-hidden-personal-data-microsoft-office/

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to open the document in desktop and remove the add-in. We have a roadmap item to allow closing either through close button or API. Until then I think closing in desktop is the only way.